# Update custom transit gateway route table instead of default - terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have the following code:

```
resource "aws_ec2_transit_gateway_route_table" "non_default" {
 transit_gateway_id = "${aws_ec2_transit_gateway.tgw.id}"
}

resource "aws_ec2_transit_gateway_route_table_association" "non_default_association" {
  transit_gateway_attachment_id  = "${aws_vpn_connection.tgw-vpn-attachment.transit_gateway_attachment_id}"
  transit_gateway_route_table_id = "${aws_ec2_transit_gateway_route_table.non_default.id}"

  depends_on = ["aws_vpn_connection.tgw-vpn-attachment"]
}

# Name default route table — This is not working either.
resource "aws_default_route_table" "default" {
  default_route_table_id = "${aws_ec2_transit_gateway.tgw.id}"

  tags = {
    Name = "HelloWorld"
  }
}
```

I want to associate the VPN gateway attachment to the non-default route table. But when I run the above code it adds it to the default route table? I need a default route table and don’t want to disable it. How can I achieve the above results?

Also when I try to add a name tag to the default route table that is not working as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the default propagation route table for an attachment. Make sure that you follow all the steps below.

1. Create a Transit Gateway (TGW).
2. Create a TGW attachment.
3. Create a TGW route table.
4. Associate the route table with the TGW attachment (ec2:TransitGatewayRouteTableAssociation).
5. Enable route propagation for the route table
   (ec2:TransitGatewayRouteTablePropagation).

After you enable propagation, the routes should appear in the specified route table instead of the default one.

> **aws_ec2_transit_gateway_route_table_propagation**
>
> Enables the specified attachment to propagate routes to the specified propagation route table.

```
resource "aws_ec2_transit_gateway_route_table_association" "association" {
  transit_gateway_attachment_id  = "${aws_vpn_connection.tgw-vpn-attachment.transit_gateway_attachment_id}"
  transit_gateway_route_table_id = "${aws_ec2_transit_gateway_route_table.non_default.id}"
}

resource "aws_ec2_transit_gateway_route_table_propagation" "propagation" {
    transit_gateway_attachment_id  = "${aws_vpn_connection.tgw-vpn-attachment.transit_gateway_attachment_id}"
    transit_gateway_route_table_id = "${aws_ec2_transit_gateway_route_table.non_default.id}"
}
```

Comment: This does not work. I have tried this for both propagation and association. But it still associates with default first and gives me error that it cannot be associated with non-default.

Comment: Have you used both association and propagation at the same time? See my updated answer. I have deployed it using CDK this way and it does propagate without any issues.

Comment: Yes, I used both together. What happens is as soon as attachment is created association is made with default route table and I get error that association cannot be made to non_default table.

Comment: Have you tried setting default_route_table_association to "disable" when creating the transit gateway?

Comment: I need the default route table as well.